# Is there an API service that will echo the exact HTTP body in the request?

Tags: web-services, http

I want to test some HTML links in Sarafi on iOS.  I want to load the safai page from a button in the app.  I want the HTML to be defined in the app, not hosted elsewhere.

Ideally I want to make a request like this

```
GET https://some-echo-service.com/
Content-Length: 17

<HTML>Test</HTML>
```

And get a response like this:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Length: 17

<HTML>Test</HTML>
```

Comment: Note you can not send  `<HTML>Test</HTML>` as the payload of a GET request, so the response will never be equivalent in this case. Did you mean POST? But a POST request is not a link. I think you could do an AJAX request to get the content of the link dinamically and set it as the content of the page

Comment: I think you can add a payload to a GET.  No one does it, but its not prohibited in the spec.  However, a POST will also do.